# Forms in Yii: how to send data back, if verification has failed

Tags: php, web, yii

I got this code:

```
public function actionJoin() {
  $user = new RUser;

  if (isset($_POST['RUser']))
      $user->attributes = $_POST['RUser'];

  $this->render('join',
    array(
        'user' => $user
    )
  );
}
```

Which will not yet allow user to register. What I want to know is how to send data back to user. I mean, if user form haven't passed verification I have to send some data back, so there is no need for user to re-enter it again.

I can do so with this:

```
$user->mail = $_POST['RUser']['mail'];
```

But it's looks like dropping back to plain PHP and not using powers of the framework here.

*Addition.* Publishing RUser class, if needed:

```
class RUser extends CFormModel
{
    public $mail;
    public $alias;

    public function safeAttributes()
    {
        return array(
            'mail', 'alias'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: show your View file code. Actialy you already have sent data from POST request to the view by code in your controller ($user->attributes = $_POST['RUser'];).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Yii you use.
 In Yii 1.1, there are no safeAttributes. You use the followings,

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('mail, alias', 'safe'),
    );
}
```

Comment: It works, tnx! So I suggest all attributes are UNSAFE by default in Yii?

Comment: Yes. For the security reason, default attributes are unsafe. User can override rules by safe, request or etc.